# Submit to $_POST via directory

Tags: php

How do I pass a post argument to `/X10/index.php` by using `/X10` as the action?

This doesn't work:

```
<form action="/X10" method="post">
```

This works but changes the url to `/X10/index.php`

```
<form action="/X10/index.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I don't have a setup to be able to try it, but does <form action="/X10/" method="post"> work?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it myself now. @user200400 Using it without the `/` did not.